# Estimating runtime from time complexity of sort algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was asked this question at school:

> If a certain sorting algorithm with time complexity O(n^2) takes 5 sec
>   to sort 50 records on a particular machine, how long will it take to
>   sort 500 records on the same machine? If the same machine is used to
>   execute a sorting algorithm with complexity O(n log n), how much time
>   will it take to sort 1024 records?

According to me the answer to the 1st part of the question is 50sec.
Is it so?

Comment: And what do you think the answer to the 2nd part is?

Comment: With the information given, it is impossible to know how long either of these operations will take.

Answer (score 0):

No don't think so. Consider the fact that the function is O(n^2), meaning that the time complexity (what some consider "time taken"), is proportional to the **square** of the number of input items passed into the algorithm. Your answer of 50 treats the algorithm as O(n) (as O(50) "=" 5, then you assume O(50*10) "=" 5*10). I won't give you the answer, but the key is to consider the O(n^2) relation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question you need to know what "time complexity O(n^2)" means, in detail.

### Mathematical definition

The mathematical definition of "time complexity O(n^2)" is that the number of basic operations (which in the case of sort are typically taken to be item moves and comparisons) is, for large enough n, bounded by some constant times n^2. With this definition, the answer to both parts is that it's impossible to say, since "large enough n" may not include n=50 or n=500, and even if it did, the big-O time complexity is an upper bound.

### Informal definition

There's an informal definition where time complexity O(n^2) means "roughly proportional to n^2". Then the first part appears answerable: 500 is 10 times larger than 50, so the runtime will be 100 times larger. The second part is still unanswerable: the constants of proportionality may be different for the two different algorithms.

But even with the informal definition, there's problems that may not be easily ignored. "Time complexity" can typically mean worst case or average case, and the particular array of size 50 may not be representative of either, and the array of size 500 may be different. For example, bubble sort has worst and average time complexity O(n^2), but if your input array of size 50 is already sorted, you're not able to predict the runtime on a randomly shuffled array of size 500.

Applying to concrete sorting algorithms, you can see the problems. Quicksort is O(n^2) worst case, and merge sort is O(n log n) worst case, so any answer can be tested against these two algorithms. If your quicksort took 5 seconds to sort 50 items, then how long would you estimate it will take to sort 500 items? Surely not 100 times as long, since that would assume both inputs provoke the worst-case behavior of quicksort. Similarly, how long would you estimate the merge sort will take to sort 1024 items? In practice, it'll take longer than quicksort (which is why quicksort variants are favored over mergesort in the real world).

### Further problems

If you want to go deeper, you can argue that comparisons and item moves are not basic operations on a computer, and therefore there's no easy translation from "time complexity" to "runtime" because "time" has a different meaning in each. For example, if you're sorting strings, the runtime will depend a lot on the length of the strings. How long does sorting an array of two strings take? Even though there's only 2 items, the sort can take arbitrarily long as the strings may be arbitrarily long.

### Summary

It looks like if you use the informal definition of complexity then you can answer "500sec" to the first part of the question (whereas the second part is always unanswerable). But I hope I've convinced you that you need to ignore both theoretical and real-world problems to produce that answer, and the correct answer is that unless you make really strong assumptions, you have to say that you can't make any predictions given the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the time complexity of the algo is O(n^2). Hence time is directly proportional to n^2.
let's consider 
t = k*n^2

where k is proportionality constant.

now solve the eqn by putting t=5 and n=50 we get

5 = k*2500

k=1/500

Now the proportionality constant will be same for any value of n.
so for n=500, put n=500 and k=1/500 we will get

t=(1/500)*500*500

t=500

so it will take 500 secs to sort 500 records.

for the second answer the value of k is calculated above will get used
so for second part

t=k*n*log(n)

t=(1/500)*1024*10

t=20.048 secs